# How to redirect an asp.net webform to another webform using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following script in my asp.net webforms project, and I want to redirect to a new page let's say NewForm.aspx in my project how do i do that?? I've tried the `window.location.href` but it didn't work. A bit of help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'DetailsForm.aspx/InsertMethod',
                    data: "{'firstname':'" + document.getElementById('firstName').value + "', 'lastname':'" + document.getElementById('lastName').value + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#firstName').val('');
                        $('#lastName').val('');
                        alert("Record saved to database successfully!");


                    },
                    error: function ()
                    { console.log('there is some error'); }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any Error? What does "but it didn't work" means to you?

Comment: i didnt get any result at all, and it didn't display any error!

Comment: If you tried `window.location.href = "Default2.aspx";` you could try `window.open('Default2.aspx');`

Comment: Does the page refresh? What's going on? Are you getting the alert box? If not, your problem is the ajax call, not necessarily the redirect...

Comment: the window.open() worked and it opened the new page in a new tab. is it possible to open it in the current tab? if not i'll just go with the window.open(). thanks @Freak_Droid